# Python 3.8 - list.append('█') but not for space characters?

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python and I am working toward writting my first program ever. I am trying to create a game where the play needs to guess a hardcoded sentence.

```
mystery_sentence='All things excellent are as difficult as they are rare'

def printGuessedLetter():
    print("This is the sentence to guess: " + ''.join(userGuesslist))


for n in mystery_sentence:
    userGuesslist.append('█')
printGuessedLetter()
```

The code above returns:

This is the sentence to guess: █████████████████████████████████████████████████████

Here's the piece of code following the above:

```
letter = input("> Enter a letter:\n>> ").lower()[0]

if letter in userGuesses:
    print("You've already submitted this letter")

else:
    attempts -= 1
    userGuesses.append(letter)
    if letter in mystery_sentence:
        print("\nNice guess")
        if attempts > 0:
            print("You have ", attempts, "remaining attempt")
            for i in range(len(mystery_sentence)):
                if letter == mystery_sentence[i]:
                    letterIndex = i
                    userGuesslist[letterIndex] = letter.upper()
            printGuessedLetter()
```

Since the sentence to guess contains spaces, I think it will be easier for the gamer to see the following: ██ ██████ █████████ ███ ██ █████████ ██ ████ ███ ████

Then, when the gamer submits a letter, it goes as followed:

Here's the sentence to guess:
██ ██████ █████████ A██ A█ █████████ A█ ████ A██ █A██

And so on.

However, I have not being able not to replace the space character by a full block. I am not sure the list.append is the right function to use.

Does anyone have an suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to replace all non-whitespace (`\S`) characters:

```
import re

mystery_sentence='All things excellent are as difficult as they are rare'
hidden = re.sub(r'\S', '█', mystery_sentence)

print(hidden)
# ███ ██████ █████████ ███ ██ █████████ ██ ████ ███ ████
```

If you really want to have this as a list:

```
userGuesslist = list(hidden)
```

---

Another option without regex:

```
hidden = ''.join(['█' if char !=' ' else ' ' for char in mystery_sentence])
print(hidden)    
# ███ ██████ █████████ ███ ██ █████████ ██ ████ ███ ████
```

or, again, if you really want to have a list instead of a string:

```
userGuesslist = ['█' if char !=' ' else ' ' for char in mystery_sentence]
```

Comment: It seems it is breaking my code as I need the following piece of code:

   for n in mystery_sentence:
        userGuesslist.append('█')
    printGuessedLetter()

to execute it. I tried replacing 'mystery_sentence' by 'hidden' but it didn't work.

Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: I added the outputs as lists, but if all you are going to do is print them, just go with the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will be helpful. You can use the Unicode character for block [here is link](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2588/index.htm)

```
block = u'\u2588'
print(block)
>> █
```

you can print out multiple like so:

```
num = 10
block = u'\u2588'
blocks = block * num
print(blocks)
>> ██████████

num = 25
block = u'\u2588'
blocks = block * num
print(blocks)
>> █████████████████████████
```

you can similarly do it like so:

```
num = 25
block = chr(9608)
blocks = block * num
print(blocks)
>> █████████████████████████
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression is an overkill for your problem. The simple way of keeping the space while replacing other characters with the block character is

```
userGuesslist = []
for n in mystery_sentence:
    if n == ' ':
        userGuesslist.append(' ')
    else:
        userGuesslist.append('█')
```

Also, notice that the `letterIndex` variable is redundant (you could just keep `i` instead) in your code.